# C Socket write HTTP GET request: error 400

Tags: c, sockets, httprequest

I am writing a small program to read finance data from download.finance.yahoo.com using sockets in C. The socket connection seem to work fine.

I can't seem to get the correct GET command to read the data from yahoo. The program reads fine from google.com, where I can read the about pages for example.

The request:

```
char resource[STR_SIZE];
strcpy(resource, "GET ");
strcat(resource, argv[3]);  //argv[3]=="/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=nsl1op"
strcat(resource, "\r\n");
...
write(fd, resource, strlen(resource));
```

This information is in the body of the page i receive when trying to request from Yahoo:

```
status code : 400
Host Header Required
host machine: r04.ycpi.ams.yahoo.net
timestamp: 1413383465.000
url: http:///d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG
```

How should the GET string be formated to work with Yahoo?

Comment: don't you need "\r\n\r\n" instead of single "\r\n"?

Comment: shouldn't your request look like "GET msg HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you read the error message and the data in the respone you can see what the problem is:

The Error Message is "Host Header Required" and the url is "`http:///d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG`", so the hostname should be added in the GET request, like

```
char resource[STR_SIZE];
strcpy(resource, "GET ");

strcat(resource, "download.finance.yahoo.com"); // or add it from argument or variable

strcat(resource, argv[3]);  //argv[3]=="/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=nsl1op"
strcat(resource, "\r\n");
...
write(fd, resource, strlen(resource));
```

Comment: This did it, also the & character in the url caused problems, so it needed to change to \& to work.

Comment: probably this won't work always, as mongoose server (e.g.) is awaitnig "\r\n\r\n"

Comment: Instead of putting the hostname in the request line, the server is really asking you to send an actual `Host` header instead: `GET /d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=nsl1op HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: download.finance.yahoo.com\r\n...`

Comment: Using `\&` is wrong, it is supposed to be just `&` by itself. No compiler will complain about that, and neither will the server. That is how it should be.

Answer (score 2):

The server is asking you to send an actual `Host` header, which is required for HTTP 1.1, or when accessing a resource on a subdomain that shares the same IP as the root domain, eg:

```
char request[STR_SIZE];
strcpy(request, "GET ");
strcat(request, argv[3]); // "/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=nsl1op"
strcat(request, " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
strcat(request, "Host: ");
strcat(request, argv[4]); // "download.finance.yahoo.com"
strcat(request, "\r\n");
// other HTTP headers as needed
strcat(request, "\r\n");
...
write(fd, resource, strlen(resource));
```

Alternatively:

```
char request[STR_SIZE];
sprintf(request,
    "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Host: %s\r\n"
    // other headers as needed
    "\r\n",
    argv[3], // "/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=nsl1op"
    argv[4]  // "download.finance.yahoo.com"
    //...
);
...
write(fd, request, strlen(request));
```